# How does one compile and link NASM code with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, nasm

Note that this question pertains specifically to Xcode 4, though additional information about other versions of Xcode are welcome.

[Part 4 of this tutorial at Cocoa Factory](http://cocoafactory.com/blog/2012/11/24/x86-64-assembly-language-tutorial-part-4/) recommends generating object code with

```
nasm-2.09.10 -f macho64 hello64.asm
```

(after putting `nasm-2.09.10` in `/usr/bin`)

and linking it with

```
gcc -m64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -o hello64 hello64.o
```

and that's just fine, but I don't want to do my compiling/linking at the command line, I'd like to just click `Build and Run` and have it all done for me. I imagine there must be some way to get Xcode to use those commands to compile my source when I `Build`, but how?